# Django: Script that executes many queries runs massively slower when executed from Admin view than when executed from shell

Tags: django, django-admin, django-orm

I have a script that loops through the rows of an external csv file (about 12,000 rows) and executes a single Model.objects.get() query to retrieve each item from the database (final product will be much more complicated but right now it's stripped down to the barest functionality possible to try to figure this out).

For right now the path to the local csv file is hardcoded into the script. When I run the script through the shell using `py manage.py runscript update_products_from_csv` it runs in about 6 seconds.

The ultimate goal is to be able to upload the csv through the admin and then have the script run from there. I've already been able to accomplish that, but the runtime when I do it that way takes more like 160 seconds. The view for that in the admin looks like...

```
from .scripts import update_products_from_csv

class CsvUploadForm(forms.Form):
    csv_file = forms.FileField(label='Upload CSV')

@admin.register(Product)
class ProductAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    # list_display, list_filter, fieldsets, etc

    def changelist_view(self, request, extra_context=None):
        extra_context = extra_context or {}
        extra_context['csv_upload_form'] = CsvUploadForm()
        return super().changelist_view(request, extra_context=extra_context)

    def get_urls(self):
        urls = super().get_urls()
        new_urls = [path('upload-csv/', self.upload_csv),]
        return new_urls + urls

    def upload_csv(self, request):
        if request.method == 'POST':
            # csv_file = request.FILES['csv_file'].file
            # result_string = update_products_from_csv.run(csv_file)

            # I commented out the above two lines and added the below line to rule out
            # the possibility that the csv upload itself was the problem. Whether I execute
            # the script using the uploaded file or let it use the hardcoded local path,
            # the results are the same. It works, but takes more than 20 times longer
            # than executing the same script from the shell.
            result_string = update_products_from_csv.run()
            print(result_string)
            messages.success(request, result_string)
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('admin:products_product_changelist'))
```

Right now the actual running parts of the script are about as simple as this...

```
import csv
from time import time

from apps.products.models import Product

CSV_PATH = 'path/to/local/csv_file.csv'

def run():
    csv_data = get_csv_data()
    update_data = build_update_data(csv_data)
    update_handler(update_data)
    return 'Finished'

def get_csv_data():
    with open(CSV_PATH, 'r') as f:
        return [d for d in csv.DictReader(f)]

def build_update_data(csv_data):
    update_data = []
    # Code that loops through csv data, applies some custom logic, and builds a list of
    # dicts with the data cleaned and formatted as needed
    return update_data

def update_handler(update_data):
    query_times = []
    for upd in update_data:
        iter_start = time()
        product_obj = Product.objects.get(external_id=upd['external_id'])
        # external_id is not the primary key but is an indexed field in the Product model
        query_times.append(time() - iter_start)
    # Code to export query_times to an external file for analysis
```

`update_handler()` has a bunch of other code checking field values to see if anything needs to be changed, and building the objects when a match does not exist, but that's all commented out right now. As you can see, I'm also timing each query and logging those values. (I've been dropping `time()` calls in various places all day and have determined that the query is the only part that's noticeably different.)

When I run it from the shell, the average query time is 0.0005 seconds and the total of all query times comes out to about 6.8 seconds every single time.

When I run it through the admin view and then check the queries in Django Debug Toolbar it shows the 12,000+ queries as expected, and shows a total query time of only about 3900ms. But when I look at the log of query times gathered by the `time()` calls, the average query time is 0.013 seconds (26 times longer than when I run it through the shell), and the total of all query times always comes out at 156-157 seconds.

The queries in Django Debug Toolbar when I run it through the admin all look like `SELECT ••• FROM "products_product" WHERE "products_product"."external_id" = 10 LIMIT 21`, and according to the toolbar they are mostly all 0-1ms. I'm not sure how I would check what the queries look like when running it from the shell, but I can't imagine they'd be different? I couldn't find anything in django-extensions runscript docs about it doing query optimizations or anything like that.

One additional interesting facet is that when running it from the admin, from the time I see `result_string` print in the terminal, it's another solid 1-3 minutes before the success message appears in the browser window.

I don't know what else to check. I'm obviously missing something fundamental, but I don't know what.

Comment: Why wouldn't you fetch all `Product`s basing on needed `external_id`s before `for upd in update_data` cycle?

Comment: Sorry I don't think I'm understanding the question. Do you mean getting all the `Product` objects in a queryset like with `Product.objects.all()`  before executing the loop, and then getting each one from the queryset? I tried that with identical results. Or do you mean getting a queryset of just the `Product` objects with a matching `external_id` value in `update_data` first? There's a more-or-less 100% overlap between `update_data` and the products table so it wouldn't really shrink the search area any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somebody on Reddit suggested that running the script from the shell might be automatically spinning up a new thread where the logic can run unencumbered by the other Django server processes, and this seems to be the answer. If I run the script in a new thread from the admin view, it runs just as fast as it does when I run it from the shell.